Functional groups in chemical formulas
I have a question about writing chemical formulas of compounds featuring functional groups. This might be simple but I haven't got answer yet. my question is when we want to write chemical formula for these kind of compounds, should we write functional groups separately (for example in alcohols) like $\ce{C2H5OH}$ or simply without specifying functional groups, like $\ce{C2H6O}$. It was confusing for me because in many articles I have seen structures that functional groups will be separated but in some other resources I see that they write formula of alcohols like $\ce{C6H10O}$ ... so finally if somebody asked me to write chemical formula for this type of compounds, which way should I use?

Come to think of it, natural languages evolve in non-logical ways. Pretty much nobody writes ethanol as C2H6O. But then again, pretty much everybody writes glucose as C6H12O6.

yes, but there should be some rules or logical conventions. I searched but can not get my answer completely

Well, both ways are fine, used depending on situation, like Ivan said.  If there is only one functional group, it usually gets highlighted. With something complicated like glucose, there's not much point.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4398/chemical-formula-of-ethanol-and-other-carbon-compounds

I think we need a retagging for notation / chemical-formula - it was more difficult to find than it should.

What is your intent to describe and who is your intended audience?
$\ce{C2H5OH}$ (or $\ce{EtOH}$) somewhat condense and thus highlight structural units.  This naturally works best if the sub units are somewhat simple, their abbreviation is easy to decipher by the reader. Graduate students in chemistry should not have difficulty to comprehend e.g. $\ce{^iPrOH}$, $\ce{t-BuOK}$, $\ce{C6H11OH}$, $\ce{BnBr}$, $\ce{BzCl}$, $\ce{p-TosCl}$.  If they advance or/and enter total synthesis, read primary literature, they quickly encounter additional abbreviations around the activation and protection of particular groups, learn to discern e.g., $\ce{-Tf}$ vs. $\ce{-OTf}$; Boc- vs. Fmoc-; THP and silyl ethers (TIPS-, TES-, TBDMS- etc).  In preparation of a publication, check other articles in the journal what abbreviations to describe structures are typically used.  Some publishers provide a list (e.g., the Encyclopedia of Organic Reagents initiated by Leo Paquette compiled hints for authors, see pages 12--16 of their pdf) to meet the needs of their readers and (help to) establish consistency within the community.  It is a convention, an agreement between chemists.
On the other hand, $\ce{C6H12O6}$ is a molecular formula which happens to be written as suggested by Hill (atoms of carbon, hydrogen; then atoms of other elements in alphabetic sort).  While it is frequently used by indexes, catalogues of suppliers of chemicals, search masks of databases, there can be good reasons to apply other criteria instead (e.g., NaCl).  A molecular formula does not carry structure information like "presence of an aldehyde".  It is by training chemists see a benzene ring reading $\ce{C6H4Cl2}$ because i) the molecular formula allows to compute a degree of unsaturation and ii) a very likely arrangement of the atoms given this molecular formula leads to this structural motif (even if one does not know [yet] if the two atoms of chlorine are in ortho, meta, or para relationship).  It is because of  context (e.g., photosynthesis, fermentation, complementary data) we may interpret $\ce{C6H12O6}$ as "glucose".  This formula can be useful e.g., to explain why there is a peak at $m/z = 180$ in the mass spectrum (see e.g. SDBS 11521). However this level of description leaves it open if we refer to the open chain form, the one as a furanose, or a pyranose.  Taken alone, the molecular formula additionally leaves it open if maybe an other isomer of glucose (e.g., fructose, or mannose) is meant.  Departing from a Hill formula, computer programs can suggest isomers (e.g., Molgen).

thanks for your explanations. so if I got it right, we will choose writing way according to situation. for instance, if we want to emphasize that there is OH group and this is an alcohol, better to write OH separately, however if I was explictly asked to write only molecular formula, I should write (for example Ethanol) like C2H6O instead of C2H5OH (because molecular formula does not carry structure information), right?

Affirmative, you got it.

Thanks for asking that relevant question of good practices!
According to IUPAC's Red Book (chapter IR-4 on formulæ), two cases can be identified :

You have little to no information on structure, or you want to focus on atoms rather than structure, you can write your molecule's 'empirical formula' (IR-4.2.1), i.e. as a "juxtaposition of the atomic symbols with appropriate (integer) subscripts to give the simplest possible formula expressing [its] composition".
Your molecule is linear and you want to provide information on its structure, then you can write its 'structural formula' (IR-4.2.3), allowing to clearly identify functional groups.

I hope this helps!

Except  C6H12O6 is neither empirical nor structural formula.

I don't see why it wouldn't be? It is written according to the Hill system, in compliance with IR-4.2.1

The empirical formula of glucose is CH2O. Question is neither about empirical, nor structural formulas, but different kinds of "ordinary" condensed formulas.

@ThomasPrévost The molecular formula of the three isomers of glucose is $\ce{C6H12O6}$ (see answer below).  But this happens to be equally true for e.g., fructose.  Its empirical formula (to use smallest integers) is $\ce{CH2O}$.  But this equally applies to formaldehyde, where (accidentally) empirical and molecular formula are identical.

@Mithoron you're right, I might have misunderstood IUPAC's definition of empirical formula. Therefore, no specific rule seems to dictate whether to separate functional groups or not I guess...
